# php iterate over an array made up of strings, instead of objects

Tags: php, arrays

I need to iterating over an array made up of strings, not objects. I've tried hunting and implementing other stackoverflow answers but dont seem to be able to make this work.

The array:

```
var_dump(`$myids`);
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "45"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "46"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "47"
}
```

I tried:

```
$myids=$_POST['myids'];
foreach ($myids as $value){
$value['myids'];
}
```

Gives the error - `Illegal string offset 'myids'`.

Then I tried:

```
$myids=$_POST['myids'];
foreach ($myids as $value){
$value->myids;
}
```

Gives the error - `Trying to access proprieties of a non object`.

So I thought maybe adding the key to the `foreach` but that wasnt the solution. At the risk of sounding dumb, what is the solution to access each value of the array?

Comment: there is no `myids`, this will work `foreach ($myids as $value) echo $value;`

Comment: oh I see! How would I then access the individual values elsewhere then, just by referencing $othervariable=$value?

Comment: a foreach just loop through iterable things, if you want to access individual values you just access them by key or index `$myids[1]` which would be 46

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there is no "myids" key in the array. You are using purely numeric IDs, so none of the keys will be named in your array.

```php
$myids=$_POST['myids'];
foreach ($myids as $value){
    echo $value;
}
```

This is unrolling each row of $myids into $value. Once it unrolls and enters the loop, you should not try to access $myids, but should work solely with $value, which represents ONLY the current row.

On the first iteration, $value will contain:
`string(2) "45"`

On the second iteration, $value will contain:
`string(2) "46"`

Third iteration:
`string(2) "47"`

As you can see, $value only ever contains string values, so there are no arrays or keys to access within. It's pulling one row on each iteration of the loop and inserting it directly into $value. As such, you only need to echo $value directly.